# How do you keep multiple requests and respond to each one after the count of requests has exceeded a certain limit?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this Post method :

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetFile(FileDetail detail)
{
}
```

I want to get 15 requests from client and send each request's response after receive 15th request from client. is there any way to keep requests and then responde them.
Thanks.

Comment: There are ways to achieve this, but I think your design may be wrong. Do you really want to block 14 clients before you answer them? Imagine that you go to a website which doesn't return an answer until 15 users try to load it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: depending from the size of your requests you could simply keep them in RAM using a queue of some sort, and have a SendRequests(queue) fire when its size reaches 15 in GetRequest. not sure I understand why, though

Comment: Thanks  tymtam. I said for example all requests come from one client

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your use case?

Comment: Thank ChoKaPeek, I understand, but I want to send a response to each request not one for all of them

Comment: Ok. But if you want to send a response to each one, then why do you need to wait until they are all received? The logic for doing that is not obvious. It's significant because this idea has the potential to cause lots of technical problems, and it's not obvious what the benefits would be.

Comment: This seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Ok Cid. It is an audio processing system that I want to send the respond of all audio files in one place for every request every 15 seconds.

Comment: Yes you keep saying you want to, but we still don't know **why**? How will this help anything? The most likely thing that will happen is that you cause performance problems and/or dropped connections for your server and the clients. If we understand what you are trying to achieve in terms of your application's business requirements and user experience, then maybe we can help you to figure out a less problematic way to do it.

Comment: So, every 15 seconds, a response (a message) should be sent to all clients requesting it? Sounds like a job for web sockets

Comment: Are you really saying that you want to keep a log of each file which has been uploaded, and that whenever a new file is uploaded, the response should contain a list of all the previously uploaded files for that user? If so, that wouldn't require you to wait for all of them to be added before you send a response.